# How to configure the YouTube Field and Mediafront modules?

Tags: media, files

I was told that the latest dev version of [MediaFront](https://www.drupal.org/project/mediafront) has support for the [YouTube field](https://www.drupal.org/project/youtube) module. How do you configure the fields and the modules so that the embedded YouTube video is displayed using the MediaFront player?

What I'm trying to do: I have a content type that allows for YouTube URLs to be copied in it creates a list of all the YouTube videos that were entered in that node. I want MediaFront to use that list of YouTube URLs in the MediaFront player.

Also in the read it says this:

```
 7. Change the Manage Display settings for Media link.

    Set up the fields in this order and with these settings:

    Field           Label       Format
    Body            Hidden      Default
    Media URL       Hidden      MediaFront Player

    In the Media URL player settings, set the MediaFront preset to
    nodeplayer. Hit Update. Hit save.
            "
```

I cannot enable the MediaFront player for the textfield "Media URL".

Comment: If you do not want to used the media front player. You can used the Youtube Field (https://www.drupal.org/project/youtube)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your textfield (admin/structure/types/manage/media/fields/[YOUR_TEXT_FIELD]).  Under the Mediafront settings Field type, set field type to 'Media' and Media Type to 'Media Content'.

You must create a mediafront preset (admin/structure/mediafront) before you can associate the textfield to mediafront player.

After your preset is setup, go to manage field of your content type (admin/structure/types/manage/[YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE]/display).  For the testfield that stores your media url, set the Format to Mediafrontplayer and set set the player settings to the Mediafront preset that you created.